# Is it possible to manually edit settings.gradle file?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle, cordova-plugins

In a Cordova project, I have a file settings.gradle which looks like:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
```

However, manually I want to edit the file and to make it look something like:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
include 'manager-A'
project(':manager-A').projectDir = new File('libs/Manager-A')
include 'manager-B'
project(':manager-B').projectDir = new File('libs/Manager-B')
```

The above script looks good and it can be built successfully using Android studio. However, when I try to execute command line: cordova build android, it cannot be built.

The error is 'manager-A' and 'manager-B' that I manually included earlier cannot be found by the command line. After checking, it turned out that the file that I manually edited was re-generated and it becomes:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
```

I'd like to ask whether it is possible to manually edit the file and that can be built as I explained above using the command line: cordova build android.

Any input is really appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing in gradle that hinders you to edit this file manually. If you experience problems they probably come from cordova.

Comment: `// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT` - this first line does not raise your attention? This file is generated, so any changes made in there will be deleted. 
Also, you already asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036614/how-to-prevent-cordova-build-command-from-auto-generating-settings-gradle).
Have you even read the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/tools.html) in this time? Have you done some [research](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783734/4908802)? Last link may be helpful to you.

Comment: Looking for similar solution, for adding a payment gateway in cordova project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I was looking to resolve same problem and found out following solution from this [npm cordova-blinkup-plugin's Page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-blinkup-plugin). You can edit the settings with as:
 1.  Open path/to/project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js
 2.  Edit `fs.writeFileSync()`  function (line 273):

```
// Write the settings.gradle file.
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(projectPath, 'settings.gradle'),
'// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT\n' +
'include ":"\n' + settingsGradlePaths.join('') +
'include ":customProject1" +
'include ":customProject2"');
```

I hope this will help.

**Update**  as suggested in another answer, In newer versions of Cordova you may get file at 
**/path/to/project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js**

Comment: See this answer-comment on this answer that shows the current file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717663/252627

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to add custom include in `setting.gradle` file.

Make a file `project.properties` and add the below lines:

```
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=manager-A
android.library.reference.3=manager-B
```

Now run `cordova build android`. This will make an entry in your `setting.gradle` file.

This answers part of the questions of how to include a module. But how to add the libs as below, still need a better way:

```
project(':manager-A').projectDir = new File('libs/Manager-A')
```

Can be done with modifying the build.js (Suggested by Sopheak Mongkul). I don't recommend, but it is good till you get a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

An update to @ankibalyan's answer:
I found that function in **path/to/project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js**, just in case anybody needed it any more :)

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the initial answer.

Comment: can't comment, below needed reputation :(